# How to call a python function inside html template in django

Tags: python, django

I want to call a python function and execute it in html template of django.

The template :

```
<li class="word-bot-sent"><p>Do you want some recommendations today? </p></li>

                               {% for obj in Recommendation %}
                                       {% if obj.user == request.user %}
                                       <li class="word-bot-sent"><p>{{ obj.title }}</p></li>
                                       <li class="word-bot-sent"><p>{{ obj.text }}</p></li>

                                       {%endif%}
                                       {% empty %}
                               {% endfor %}
                               i want to execute the function here
```

I want to delete the rows in the recommendation table with that function.
So what to do. Could someone help please. Thanks so much

Comment: What do you want to do? The general rule is to avoid adding too much logic to the templates. If you need to calculate something do it in the view and add it to the context, or add functions to the model so you can access it through the object.

Answer (score 0):

you can write functions and register them as tags, and call them in your html, follow django's document:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters